# Segment Builder - Any way to 'paste' in multiple URLs (due to varying name conventions/etc)?

Tags: adobe-analytics

I'm trying to build a couple of segments based on entry url. Unfortunately, the site has inconsistent name conventions/url structures so using 'Starts With' or some of the other search operators isn't much help. Is there a way to 'paste' (and use a separator) a list of various entry urls or am I going to have to do this one by one?

**Current (inefficient)**

::Entry URL = URL 1 OR Entry URL = URL 2, etc..

**Hoping for (more efficient)**

:Entry URL matches any of these: URL1, URL2, etc (pasted in single field?)

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Use match type "matches regex" and list your values with "|" in one field.

URL1|URL2